# Weird behavior in xpage/javascript variable assignment

Tags: javascript, xpages

I'm having this weird behavior and I'm not sure if it's me not misunderstanding variables or it's an xpage issue

I have a document with a field called "hours" and it has a value of 8.
Here is my simplified code .

```
var xHrs = doc.getItemValueDouble('hours');
println (xHrs);  // at this point, hours is 8
doc.replaceItemValue('hours', 0);
return xHrs;  // returns 0;
```

Why is xHrs back to 0 when I replace the document value to 0?  How do I break the link?

Thanks in advance for the help :)

R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are that the code is being executed more than once.

Try wrapping the code with `${javascript:` rather than `#{javascript:`

```
${javascript: 
var xHrs = doc.getItemValueDouble('hours');
doc.replaceItemValue('hours', 0);
return xHrs;  
}
```

The code will be executed only once with the preceding $.

Comment: Wow... you are right..  been breaking my head for the past 3 hours and it turns out that it was being called twice.  Darn, I should have caught that!!  Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as the solution!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that setting your xHrs variable as you do creates a function expression that returns the value of the 'hours' field. You change the value of the field and the function returns the new value.

I'm not sure about breaking the chain in an efficient manner, but maybe if you create a second variable to hold the xHrs value?

Comment: I tried using a second variable and no luck :(   I tried using a function to return the value and no luck either.  Weird thing is that the the issue occurs in in a function being called within another function.  If I move my code to the parent function, no issues.